# Discord.js Triva Bot Issues

Tags: discord.js

I am developing a simple Discord trivia bot (using Discord.js). I am using the code below, but Glitch is giving me errors saying `userAnswer is not defined` and `answered is not defined` etc
[image]
The code should select a random question, then ask it and wait for an answer and say whether it is correct or incorrect. I have no idea why the errors are occurring.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const { Client, MessageAttachment, MessageEmbed, MemberAdd, RichEmbed } = require('discord.js'); 
const client = new Client(); 

client.on("ready", () => {
    client.user.setActivity("ihs help",{
        type:"STREAMING",
        url:"https://www.twitch.tv/ihsbot"
    })
    console.log("I am ready!");

client.on("guildMemberAdd", member => {
  member.send(
    "Welcome to the server! Please follow our server's rules. Have fun! "
  )
})

client.on('message', message, msg => {
  if (answered == false) {
    userAnswer = msg;
    if (userAnswer == cAnswer) {
      message.reply ("got it right!")
    }
    else {
      message.reply ("got it wrong!")
    }
    answered = true; cAnswer = ""; userAnswer = "";
  }

  if (msg.startsWith("ihs quiz")) {
    answered = true;
    cAnswer = "";
    userAnswer = "";
    number = 3;
    random = Math.floor (Match.random() * (number - 1 + 1)) + 1;
    switch (random) {
      case 1: message.channel.send ("**Question** n\A) Answer1 n\B) Answer2 n\C) Answer3 n\D) Answer4"); cAnswer = "a"
      case 2: message.channel.send ("**Question** n\A) Answer1 n\B) Answer2 n\C) Answer3 n\D) Answer4"); cAnswer = "a"
      case 3: message.channel.send ("**Question** n\A) Answer1 n\B) Answer2 n\C) Answer3 n\D) Answer4"); cAnswer = "a"
    }
    answered = false;
  }
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

Comment: variables should be defined using "let" or "const"

Comment: and you"re testing on something undefined which will show you errors

Comment: maybe you should add on your question a description of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.JS isnt like PHP, where you can just put the value to variable, but you must first declare it, there are 3 main types: const = constant variable, that you dont change, let and var = variables, that can change, for mor info about the diference, this is nice article [What's the difference between using "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var). To declare variable, do `var varName` (same for let and const).